# Dart FFI bindings to ***struct: iterate over 'result'

Tags: dart, ffi

I'm trying to write FFI bindings to a C library that has a function that uses ***Struct as one of its parameters:

```
typedef struct {
    char *name;
    char *value;
} StructType;

extern void theFunction(StructType ***list);
```

which should be called, and the result used, as:

```
const StructType **struct_list;
theFunction(&struct_list);

for (int i = 0; struct_list[i]; i++) {
    StructType *entry = struct_list[i];
    printf("name: %s, value %s\n", entry->name, entry->value);
}
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to create the Dart FFI bindings for this. I've tried with `Pointer<Pointer<Pointer<StructType>>>`. The actual binding (the `lookup().asFunction()`) seems to work, the *call* to the actual function seems to work, but I just can't figure out how to iterate over the `***struct_list` after the function call to get to the list of `StructType`s.

Would anybody have a small example on how this can be achieved?

**[EDIT]**
I am so close... Just having trouble accessing the individual members of the struct. Here is the method I'm currently using. Note that I'm using a struct called "Item" here, I think that makes things easier to read:

```dart
class Item extends Struct {
    external Pointer<Utf8> name;
    external Pointer<Utf8> value;
}

late int Function(Pointer<Pointer<Pointer<Item>>>) getItems;
typedef getItemsNative_t = Int32 Function(Pointer<Pointer<Pointer<Item>>>);

getItems = library.lookup<NativeFunction<getItemsNative_t>('get_items').asFunction();

Pointer<Pointer<Pointer<Item>>> pppItem = calloc();
getItems(pppItem);

Pointer<Pointer<Item>> ppItem = pppItem.value;
int idx = 0;
Pointer<Item> pItem = ppItem.elementAt(idx).value; // *item
while (pItem != nullptr) {
    Item item = pItem.ref; // IS THIS CORRECT?
    print('name = ${item.name.toDartString()}');
    print('value = ${item.value.toDartString()}');
    pItem = ppItem.elementAt(++idx).value;
}
calloc.free(pppItem);
```

This *almost* works. It 'gets to' every Item, except that each member access returns the value for 'name', not 'value'.

I must be doing something wrong at the line with the 'IS THIS CORRECT' comment, but I can't figure out what it is. Anybody has any idea/suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I am so embarrassed. My real code is a bit more complicated than I showed above, and it turns out my test case was incorrect :(

So, the above (under [EDIT]) all works. Closing this.